# How to Read the response from Jmeter command prompt console and store in a variable in Beanshell script

Tags: jmeter

How to Read the response from Jmeter command prompt console and store in a variable in Beanshell script

For Ex:-

I want to read a path which is displaying in console after running SQL Query, SO I want store that value in variable

SELECT VALUE FROM RBT_PROPERTIESS WHERE PARAM='RUN_PATH' AND TYPE='CAL';
/data/RRT/RRT_cal/

Answer (score 0):

If you need `/data/RRT/RRT_cal/` (which looks like the folder where your JMX file lives in) bit following Beanshell code snippet can help. It uses [FileServer](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/services/FileServer.html) class [getBaseDir()](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/services/FileServer.html#getBaseDir%28%29) method which returns location relative to which file paths are being generated.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

FileServer fs = FileServer.getFileServer();
String baseDir = fs.getBaseDir();
vars.put("BASEDIR",baseDir);
```

or alternatively you can use [user.dir](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) Java System property which returns user working directory

```
String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
vars.put("USERDIR", userDir);
```

See [How to use BeanShell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more examples and tecnhiques